# Spark query to aggregate and update values in a table for a parent child relationship

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following tables (Each table has other columns as well, but not needed here)

**Item table**

```
      user_id, party_id, parent_user_id
        1,        X,      null
        2,        X,       1
        3,        X,       1
        4,        Z,       null
        5,        Z,       4
        6,        Y,       null
        7,        Y,       6
        8,        Y,       6
        1,        Y,       null
```

Where *null* **parent_user_id** indicates that its a parent user and then whichever columns have a parent_user_id, it denotes that its a child user.

**Priority table**

```
      user_id, party_id, priority
          1,      X,     0.3 
          2,      X,     0.8
          3,      X,     0.5 
          4,      Z,     0.1
          5,      Z,     0.2
          6,      Y,     0.7
          7,      Y,     0.4
          8,      Y,     0.5
          1,      Y,     0.3
```

What I want to do is write a spark query to convert the priority table as below.
Logic should be, for every parent user and its child user, calculate its max priority i.e max(parent user priority, child user1 priority, child user2 priority, ....) and then change the priorities to reflect the max value for that parent and all its child (as mentioned in the below updated table).

**Priority table**

```
      user_id, party_id, priority
          1,      X,     0.8 
          2,      X,     0.8
          3,      X,     0.8 
          4,      Z,     0.2
          5,      Z,     0.2
          6,      Y,     0.7
          7,      Y,     0.7
          8,      Y,     0.7
          1,      Y,     0.3
```

How do you write a spark job to accomplish this? How do you even start by writing a basic sql query first to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is based on following points.

1) Joining `item` and `priority` table based on `user_id` and `party_id`.

2) Replacing null `parent_user_id` with it's `user_id` (This does the magic)

3) **Drop unnecessary columns if required.

4) Apply window function and find max priority among `party_id`.

```
val itemTbl = Seq((1, "X", None),
      (2, "X", Some(1)),
      (3, "X", Some(1)),
      (4, "Z", None),
      (5, "Z", Some(4)),
      (6, "Y", None),
      (7, "Y", Some(6)),
      (8, "Y", Some(6)),
      (1, "Y", None)).toDF("user_id", "party_id", "parent_user_id")


    val priorityTbl = Seq((1, "X", 0.3),
      (2, "X", 0.8),
      (3, "X", 0.5),
      (4, "Z", 0.1),
      (5, "Z", 0.2),
      (6, "Y", 0.7),
      (7, "Y", 0.4),
      (8, "Y", 0.5),
      (1, "Y", 0.3)).toDF("user_id", "party_id", "priority")

  //replace null parent_user_id with actual value in Item table.
    val replaceExp = when(col("parent_user_id") isNull, col("user_id")).otherwise(col("parent_user_id"))
    val itemTblModf = itemTbl.withColumn("parent_user_id", replaceExp)

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("party_id", "parent_user_id")
itemTblModf.join(priorityTbl, itemTbl("user_id") <=> priorityTbl("user_id") && itemTbl("party_id") <=> priorityTbl("party_id"))
  .drop(priorityTbl("user_id"))
  .drop(priorityTbl("party_id"))
  .withColumn("new_priority", max("priority") over windowSpec).show(200, false)
```

**Result**

```
+-------+--------+--------------+--------+------------+
|user_id|party_id|parent_user_id|priority|new_priority|
+-------+--------+--------------+--------+------------+
|1      |Y       |1             |0.3     |0.3         |
|1      |X       |1             |0.3     |0.8         |
|2      |X       |1             |0.8     |0.8         |
|3      |X       |1             |0.5     |0.8         |
|4      |Z       |4             |0.1     |0.2         |
|5      |Z       |4             |0.2     |0.2         |
|6      |Y       |6             |0.7     |0.7         |
|7      |Y       |6             |0.4     |0.7         |
|8      |Y       |6             |0.5     |0.7         |
+-------+--------+--------------+--------+------------+
```

I wont say my solution is very efficient one yet it's a workable solution.The same result can also be achievable using RDD in more functional way.

Comment: This looks like a workable solution. The only issue is that the user_id : 1 and party_id : Y should be 0.3 instead of 0.7. If you look at the item table, user_id : 1 and party_id : Y is a parent user. So it should be 0.3.

Comment: Well I'm working on tat. Interesting scenario though.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!